# If $(\mathbb{R},V,+)$ is a vector space with dimension = $n$, then $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I wrote the following proof. I'm a bit unsure about my proof because it feels a bit basic. I've seen fancier proofs here and I'm worried I made wrong assumptions or that I'm not precise enough.

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field of real numbers. Prove that if the dimension of $V$ is $n$ then $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, it has a basis, let's name it $B$.
Define $B := \{v_1,....,v_n\}$

Now, define the following map $T : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. This map sends each $v \in V$ to it's coordinate vector (:= $co_B(v)$ ) with respect to basis B.

To prove that T is an isomorphism, we can prove the following three things:

1. T is a linear map
2. T is injective
3. T is surjective

T is a linear map $\iff$ $T(\lambda v_a + \phi v_b) = \lambda T(v_a)+\phi T(v_b)$.
(I proof this in a manner that is correct, I think, but it's a lot of letters so I will not write it down here.)

T is injective $\iff$ $\forall v_1,v_2 \in V: T(v_a)=T(v_b) \rightarrow v_a = v_b$.
Proof: Take $v_a,v_b \in V$ arbitrarly. Because of the fact that $B$ is a basis for V, we can write $v_a$ and $v_b$ as follows:
$v_a = c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n$ and $v_b = b_1v_1+\cdots+b_nv_n$.

Imagine that $T(v_a)=T(v_b)$, this would mean that $(c_1,\cdots,c_n) = (b_1,\cdots,b_n)$
Then it follows that $v_a = v_b$. So $T$ is injective.

$T$ is surjective $\iff$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \exists v \in V: f(v) = x$.
Let $x = (a_1,...a_n)$ be an arbitrary vector $\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then consider the following vector in V: $v := a_1v_1+\cdots+a_nv_n$. Then it follows from the definition of our map $T$, that $T(v) = co_B(v) = x$. So $T$ is surjective.

Now we can say that $T$ is an isomorfism and that $\mathbb{R}^n \cong V$

Comment: It might be simpler to think about the map $\Bbb R^n\to V$ which, for a fixed ordered basis $(b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n)$ of $V$, sends $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ to $x_1b_1+\cdots+x_nb_n$. Then we can easily check linearity and all the rest of it. Then it follows its inverse $V\to\Bbb R^n$ is also an isomorphism, but it's easier to check all of that for the map $\Bbb R^n\to V$

Comment: *The key observation here:* The two properties of a basis are directly connected to the coordinate map being an isomorphism: linear independence gives injectivity (uniqueness of coordinates), whereas spanning gives surjectivity (existence of coordinates).

Comment: @SammyBlack actually in the direction used in the question the linear independence gives that the function is well-defined and the spanning gives that it is not partial (ie defined on all of V). These are of course the dual properties to injectivity and surjectivity under inverting a correspondence.